# What does "Swedish parents are entitled to 480 paid parental leave days for each child" mean?

Tags: word-usage

> Swedish parents are entitled to 480 paid parental leave days for each child

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sweden encourages parents to take a lot of time off when they have a baby.  I googled this sentence and the context indicates that this is a pooled amount of days: i.e. both parents could take an equal 240 days off (adding up to 480), or it could be unequal (one parent taking 60 and another 420).  However, each parent is entitled to 60 days that can't be taken away from them by the other parent (unless they are a single parent).

Answer (score 1):

It means Swedish people that have children can have 480 days off work starting from when their child is born (or possibly a bit earlier). It is not specified if it applies to both parents or just one, but I would presume only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

This is referring to paternity leave. It means that when a couple has a child, both parents are allowed to take paid time off from their jobs to care for the baby. The total number of days the couple can take is 480. They split these days between them, so both the mother and the father have time to bond with and care for the child before returning to work.